# How to take advantage of break lines in a column to make a MultiIndex?

Tags: pandas

My input is a dataframe (made from this link https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Abbreviation': ['ADT', 'ET', 'GMT'],
 'Time zone name': ["Atlantic Daylight Time\nADST – Atlantic Daylight Saving Time\nAST – Atlantic Summer Time\nHAA – Heure Avancée de l'Atlantique (French)",
  'Eastern Time',
  'Greenwich Mean Time\nUTC – Coordinated Universal Time\nGT – Greenwich Time']})
```

| Abbreviation | Time zone name |
| --- | --- |
| ADT | Atlantic Daylight Time ADST – Atlantic Daylight Saving Time AST – Atlantic Summer Time HAA – Heure Avancée de l'Atlantique (French) |
| ET | Eastern Time |
| GMT | Greenwich Mean Time UTC – Coordinated Universal Time GT – Greenwich Time |

Some time zones can have a sort of equivalent. For example `GMT` has two equivalents. But some others have no equivalents like `ET`.

I'm trying to extract the equivalent time zones and make them as multindex.

My expected output is this :

```
                                 Time zone name                                 Details
Abbreviation Equivalent                                                                
ADT          ADST        Atlantic Daylight Time           Atlantic Daylight Saving Time
             AST         Atlantic Daylight Time                    Atlantic Summer Time
             HAA         Atlantic Daylight Time  Heure Avancée de l'Atlantique (French)
ET           NaN                   Eastern Time                                     NaN
GMT          UTC            Greenwich Mean Time              Coordinated Universal Time
             GT             Greenwich Mean Time                          Greenwich Time
```

For that, I made the code below but unfortunately the row for the timzeone `ET` is missing :

```
first_split = df['Time zone name'].str.split('\n')

second_split = first_split.explode().str.split(' – ', expand=True)

df['Time zone name'] = first_split.str[0]

final = pd.concat([df, second_split], axis=1).rename(columns={0: 'Equivalent', 1: 'Details'})

final = final.dropna(subset='Details')

final = final.set_index(['Abbreviation', 'Equivalent'])
```

Can you help me guys fix my code ? I'm open to any other idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) or [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for remove first duplicated values:

```
final = final[final.index.duplicated() | ~final.index.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

---

```
final = final[final['Abbreviation'].duplicated() | 
              ~final['Abbreviation'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Or use [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) with [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) and [`Index.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.value_counts.html):

```
final = final[final['Details'].notna() | 
              (final.index.map(final.index.value_counts()) == 1)]
```

Instead:

```
final = final.dropna(subset='Details')
```

Another complete solution with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and forward filling missing values for `Time zone name` column:

```
final = (df.assign(**{'Time zone name':df['Time zone name'].str.split('\n')})
           .explode('Time zone name'))

final[['Equivalent','Details']] = final['Time zone name'].str.extract('(.*)\s*–\s*(.*)')

final['Time zone name'] = (final['Time zone name'].where(final['Equivalent'].isna())
                                                  .ffill())

final = final[final.index.duplicated() | ~final.index.duplicated(keep=False)]

final = final.set_index(['Abbreviation', 'Equivalent'])

print (final)
                                 Time zone name  \
Abbreviation Equivalent                           
ADT          ADST        Atlantic Daylight Time   
             AST         Atlantic Daylight Time   
             HAA         Atlantic Daylight Time   
ET           NaN                   Eastern Time   
GMT          UTC            Greenwich Mean Time   
             GT             Greenwich Mean Time   

                                                        Details  
Abbreviation Equivalent                                          
ADT          ADST                 Atlantic Daylight Saving Time  
             AST                           Atlantic Summer Time  
             HAA         Heure Avancée de l'Atlantique (French)  
ET           NaN                                            NaN  
GMT          UTC                     Coordinated Universal Time  
             GT                                  Greenwich Time
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. Your complete solution gives me the expected output.